# Defining shortcuts

Tags: macros

I am using `$\longrightarrow{}$` at many places in my document. I should say around two to three times per page. 
I was wondering if there is a way to assign a shortcut (i.e. `lra`) and wherever I use `lra` it will put `$\longrightarrow{}$`.

So far I am getting by with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> & <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

Comment: As an alternative to the TeX solutions below, you can define a shortcut/macro in your editor.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\def\lra{\ensuremath\longrightarrow}
\def\lras{\ensuremath\longrightarrow\ }
\begin{document}
\noindent%
The \lra without a trailing space.

\noindent%
The \lras with a trailing space.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Given the "I am very new to TeX" statement in the question, I'd rephrase this with `\newcommand` rather than `\def`.

Answer (score 23):

Expanding on Frabjous's answer, I would do this:

```
\usepackage{xspace}

...

\newcommand{\lra}{\ensuremath{\longrightarrow{}}\xspace}
```

This gives you a `\lra` command that is sensitive to the trailing space without defining two macros for it.

Comment: As such it works great. How to use this for shortcut  $\xrightarrow[\text{Unicode text 1}]{\text{Unicode text 2}}$

Comment: @Mark: What is the package `xspace` most commonly useful for?

Comment: @nightowl: The package `xspace` provides the command `\xspace`, which does or does not add a space depending on whether there's a punctuation sign right after it. `Foo\xspace .` will expand to `Foo.`, `Foo\xspace Bar` will expand to `Foo Bar`. This comes in handy for new macros which will behave correctly no matter what follows. Here's an interesting question on `xspace`'s behavior toward different punctuation signs: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15252/why-does-xspace-behave-differently-for-parenthesis-vs-braces-brackets

Answer (score 11):

I'd do it like this:

`\newcommand{\lra}{\ensuremath{\longrightarrow{}}}`

Thanks to ensuremath, this will work both inside and outside of math mode -- with no need for $...$.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `let` which allows you to copy the content of a command into a new command.

```
 \let\lra\longrightarrow

 $\lra$
```

Comment: What is the benefit of using `\let` in this case versus `\def`?

Comment: @CarlMorris It is slightly more efficient as it assigns a pointer to the existing definition.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides, this doesn't work with environments, right?, e.g. \let\v\verbatim

Comment: @PatrickT Yes it will not work with environements or with LaTeX commands that take arguments etc..