# Why does \xspace behave differently for parenthesis vs. braces/brackets?

Tags: spacing, xspace

Consider:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xspace}
\begin{document}
(something\xspace)

[something\xspace]

\{something\xspace\}
\end{document}
```

Or more to the point:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\something}{something\xspace}
\begin{document}
(\something)

[\something]

\{\something\}
\end{document}
```

Either of these yields:

[image: xspace output image]

So the question is, why does `\xspace` produce a space before `]` and `}` but not `)`? I find this very annoying. I would much rather it produces no space in any of these three circumstances. I know I can get rid of the space by using `\xspace{}` or `\something{}`, but it sort of defeats the purpose, which is primarily to define my own macros so that I don't need to think about whether I need `{}` afterwards, and can just use the macro as if it were a word.

Do people consider this a bug? And if so, how should I report it?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The author(s) of `xspace` didn't included `]` and `\}` in the list of exceptions. Why? No Idea. But there is `\xspaceaddexceptions` which allows you to add them:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xspace}
\xspaceaddexceptions{]\}}
\newcommand{\something}{something\xspace}
\begin{document}
(\something)

[\something]

\{\something\}
\end{document}
```

#### Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: effectively the author(s) didn't include `}` and `]` in the list of exceptions; I copied the original list in my answer. Since you answered first and both our answers are basically the same, I don't mind deleting mine. I just wanted you to notice that you can remove the "It seems that" part of your answer.

Comment: @Gonzalo: Thanks. I don't think any of the answers must be deleted. You also have the complete list of characters which is interesting.

Comment: Thanks, I upvoted both but accepted this, since it was first.

Comment: I used `\xspaceaddexceptions{[]\{\}}` because opening brackets are also symbols which cause some whitespace in my text.

Answer (score 26):

The `xspace` package uses a list of exceptions to decide when to add a space; the original definition of the list is:

```
\def\@xspace@exceptions@tlp{%
,.’/?;:!~-)\ \/\bgroup\egroup\@sptoken\space\@xobeysp
\footnote\footnotemark
}
```

As you see, `)` is included in the list, but `}` and `]` are not, so `xspace` will add a space. If you want to remove the space for this characters, add `}` and `]` to the list by using `\xspaceaddexceptions{]\}}`.