# Which IDE/Editor and "compiler" do you use for TeX/LaTeX? - How do macros work?

Tags: macros, packages, miktex, texworks

I've been using LaTeX for a few weeks now, with TeXworks, and have found it quite frustrating.

I'm running MiKTeX 2.8 on Windows 7 x64 with TeXworks 0.3.

Reasons why I find TeX frustrating:

- Very difficult to install packages, and get them running in my code (sometimes impossible, i.e. with `xy-pic`)
- When I write code, it takes a while (dollar signs everywhere)
- I also end up using `\\[2mm]` all over the place

Quick related question, how do I create macros? — Basically I want to replace `$\rightarrow$` with `\im` (implies) etc. It would also be helpful if I could define keyboard shortcuts for this type of thing (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> = `$\forall%`, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> = `$\exists$`, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> = `$\rightarrow$`, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> = `$\leftrightarrow$` etc.).

**So which TeX, LaTeX or other package would you recommend I use for typesetting, with which IDE/text-editor?**

Purpose: For typing up Discrete Mathematics Lectures (Graph Theory, Logic Theory etc.)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). I can understand your frustration, LaTeX takes some time getting used to, it has its very own way for some things. But don't despair, it definitely pays off `:)`. Both of your questions actually have been asked here already. I'll write up an answer with links to the respective questions.

Comment: You can tell MiKTeX to automatically install packages. Simply go to Start -> MiKTeX 2.8 -> Maintenance (Admin) -> Settings (Admin). Under "General" you find "package installation", you can set it to install on the fly. This of course requires an online repository, if you haven't already go to the package manager (-> Maintenance (Admin) -> Package Manager), and select "Repository" "Change Repository" "Internet" and choose a server near you

Comment: and for the implies: write `\newcommand{\imp}{$\rightarrow$}` in the preamble. Shortcuts are either customizable in your editor, so have a look at the [TexWorks manual](http://ftp.ctex.org/pub/tex/tools/editors/TeXworks/manual.pdf), or consider using [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/), it can assign anything to any key combo

Comment: Based on your remark about Alt+A = `$\forall$`, etc., I'll ask: are you putting a dollar sign around *each character in mathematics*? You ought to be doing something more like `$\forall\epsilon\exists\delta:\epsilon < \delta$`, or the like. If you have a long list of equations, or a chained equation, you might want to be using displayed math environments instead, *e.g.* the `align` or `gather` environments provided by `amsmath.sty`. (If these are not your problems, my apologies.)

Comment: Have you ever considered a Linux, and if just as a virtual machine? I once had to set up a LaTeX environment in Windows and found it quite painful, too. But it's much less so in a Linux distro with the blessings of proper package management, a well-usable command line etc.

Comment: I think it is the best for both parties if you can just include a frustrating paragraph or mathematical equation for you. Then people on this forum would be willing to fix, if any, unnecessary items, syntax mistakes etc.

Comment: If this is a question about IDEs, then it's a duplicate of [LaTEX editors/IDEs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides). If it's a question about installing packages on MikTeX Then it's a duplicate of [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows). If it's a question about TeXworks shortcuts then [BAM](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22481/can-i-configure-shortcut-keys-in-texworks). In any of these cases, this should be closed.

Comment: This is far too many questions (and complaints) in one to fit our format: 'not a real question' I think.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Regarding your reasons:

- Package installation mainly depends on the TeX distribution and on the operation system.

  - [TeX Live](http://www.tug.org/texlive/) has been providing a package manager since 2008, it's called TeX Live Manager aka tlmgr, running on Windows, Linux, Mac and further Unixes.
  - [MiKTeX](http://miktex.org/) also provides a package manager, mpm, even for a longer time
  - Manual installation should always be possible, there are explanations and howtos, also on this site, see for example: [How can I manually install a package on MiKTeX (Windows)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows)
- Writing code with many `$` signs is usual - you could use `\(` and `\)` instead though I guess you don't like that either
- Writing `\\[2mm]` is a sign that your layout requires improvement. Spacing should be adjusted in the preamble, for example using the [`setspace`](http://ctan.org/pkg/setspace) package or by customizing environments.

Create your own macros for example by `\newcommand` or `\newenvironment`. Not only for having shortcuts, but also for a consistent document which can easily be changed later. You can use `\ensuremath` in your macro definitions, so your macros will work both in math and in text mode, saving you typing `$`.

Generally, I recommend using [TeX Live](http://www.tug.org/texlive/). The version 2011 has just been released. for the editor, I recommend [TeXworks](http://www.tug.org/texworks/) as easy and quick editor and [TeXnicCenter](http://www.texniccenter.org/) as complex and very capable editor. TeXnicCenter provides auto-completion of source code which can be useful in your case, and of course shortcuts you asked for. You can even extend the auto-completion yourself, see [How to add new auto-complete options in TeXnicCenter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17240/how-to-add-new-auto-complete-options-in-texniccenter).

You might have a further look at:

- [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides)
- [What are the advantages of TeXLive over MikTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20036/what-are-the-advantages-of-texlive-over-miktex)

Comment: `\\[2mm]` should be replaced by setting `\parskip`, it isn't the line spacing.

Comment: @Leo Liu: Possibly, if the OP uses it between paragraphs, he didn't write it. So, good addition. In general \\ is for breaking lines, not paragraphs, in text as well as in tables and multiline math where `\parskip` would not be so meaningful.

Comment: Thank you very much. Quick question before I move to TeXLive, how does the compilation speed compare? Is there a x64 version?

Answer (score 15):

Here are some thoughts to the points you made in your post:

**packages**: As Tom Bombadil said in his comment, MiKTeX usually installs packages *on the fly*, if you set it up correctly. Installing fonts is a bit more tricky sometimes. I don't know anything about specific pitfalls of `xy-pic`. If you can't get it running for some reason, check if there's a question about it on tex.sx, and if not, you're welcome to ask a question about it.

**dollar-signs**: I don't use LaTeX for math, but my understanding is that math typesetting is actually one of the main strengths of it. I'd be surprised if there were any easier and similarly comprehensive way of math typesetting.

**macros**: [Defining shortcuts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7793/defining-shortcuts)

**keyboard shortcuts in TeXworks**: [Can I configure shortcut keys in TeXworks?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22481/can-i-configure-shortcut-keys-in-texworks) might or might not help.

**editors**: [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides) lists a lot of editors, [TeX Community Polls](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1564/tex-community-polls/1567#1567) has a poll regarding the popularity of editors in this community.

**General Thoughts**: We strive to have only one question per post. If you have several questions and they all haven't been asked on here, it's absolutely no problem to post several questions. This way, other users can benefit maximally from the problems and solutions other users have come up with. Hence, I think this question here should be closed. This doesn't mean we don't want to answer your questions, this question 1) simply doesn't fit the question format and 2) contains questions that have already been asked and thus partially is a duplicate. If, after reading the questions I pointed you at and searching for other questions on tex.sx regarding your problems, you still can't figure something out, just go ahead and ask one or several questions.

Comment: I agree with your last comment. People on TeX.SE are a lot more friendly to simple questions than over on stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

With regards to "which editor to use" and "how to configure keyboard shortcuts"... I came to LaTeX only recently, but I think I can recommend [Texmaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/).

Texmaker is a cross-platform editor that integrates nicely with a MiKTeX installation on Windows. Make `miktex\bin` show up in `PATH`, and Texmaker has everything it needs. If a package is missing, MiKTeX's excellent auto-installation feature will come up and install the package for you... I actually use this setup under WINE in Linux, because IMHO it beats any other combination of editor and LaTeX distribution hands-down.

Texmaker has a good auto-completion feature, and allows free definition of keyboard shortcuts ("Options" / "Configure" / "Editor") as well as user macros and commands (menu "User"). Together with some smart `\newcommand` LaTeX macros, it has saved me *much* typing this way. The integrated PDF viewer is nice too, opening the PDF at the current source position and allowing to jump from any place of the PDF to the corresponding LaTeX source file / line.